# Transformations in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $f, f_1, ..., fn   $  on a vector space $V$ such that $ f_1(x)=f_n(x)=0   $ means $f(x)=0$.

Show there are scalars so

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}f_{i}(x)= f(x) $$

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've ecountered annihilator functions, which take any element s in your set S to zero, that should help a lot with the proof

Answer (score 1):

I have made an edit to my solution. In the first solution, I considered the space $V$ to be an inner product space, which was not an assumption. I am not going to delete it, but rather put an extension, as a more general solution.

Thanks to @amd, for directing me to the right way.

**With inner product assumption**

For every linear functional $f(x)$, there exists a $v \in V$ such that

$$f(x)= <x,v>$$

Assume $f(x)= <x,v>$ and $f_k(x)= <x,v_k>$.

If for a special $x_0\in V$

$f_k(x_0)=0 \hspace{0.3cm} \forall k \implies <x_0,v_k>=0 \hspace{0.3cm} \forall k$

So, $x_0$ is perpendicular to all $v_k$ ($x_0$ is in the orthogonal complement space of $W=span\{v_k,k=1,...,n\}$)and, by assumption, we should get

$<x_0,v>=0$. Now, if $v$ is not in $W$, then it should be perpendicular to $W$, which then results in $<v,v>=0$, which not true,as we assume $||v||\neq0$. So we have to accept that $v$ is actually in $W$. Therefore, it can be written as a linear combination of $v_k$.

$$v=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kv_k$$

Then

$$f(x)=<x,v>=<x,\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kv_k>=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k<x,v_k>=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kf_k(x)$$

---

**Extension: More general approach**

As suggested by @amd, I am going to consider the definition of annihilator of a subset $S$ of $V$ as below

$$ann(S)=\{g \in V^* | g(s)=0 \hspace{0.2cm}\forall s \in S\}$$

Where $V^*$ is the dual space of $V$. Then, define

$S=\{ x\in V | f_k(x)=0 \hspace{0.2cm} \forall k=1,...,n\}$.

Firstly, $ann(S)$ is a linear sub-space of $V^*$. Because, if $f,g \in ann(S)$ and $x\in S$

$f+g(x)=f(x)+g(x)=0 \implies f+g \in ann(S)$

$(\alpha f)(x) = \alpha f(x)=0$

where $\alpha$ belongs to the field.

Finally, notice that due to

$$f_1(x)=f_2(x)=...=f_n(x)=0 \implies f(x)=0$$

we can conclude that the null-space $N(f)$ of $f(x)$ is a super-set of $\cap_{i}N_i$, where $N_i$ is the null-space of $f_i(x)$.

So, if $\cap_{i}N_i\subseteq N(f)$ is true, then $f(x)$ can be written as a linear combination of $\{f_i(x), i=1,...,n\}$

If you need more information on annihilators, here is a concise introduction

[https://www.math.ku.edu/~mandal/math790/annihilator.pdf](https://www.math.ku.edu/%7Emandal/math790/annihilator.pdf)

Comment: $V$ isn’t stated as being an inner product space. How do you define $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ here?

Comment: @amd, I just assumed it to be an inner product space. If it is not the case, let me know and I would delete the answer.

Comment: You might be able to modify your answer to work without an inner product. Instead of the orthogonal complement of $W$ you’ll need to use its annihilator.

Comment: @amd, please have a look to see if the extension is fine. It was interesting to know about "annihilators". Thanks

Comment: In the extended approach, how do the annhilators tie into solving the question?